# How to prove that if a $3 \times 3$ matrix has two equal rows, it has no inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inverse

In my maths classes in school we have said that if a matrix has two equal rows then it has no inverse.

I can see this by calculating that the determinant of any $3 \times 3$ matrix with two equal rows is always $0$.

I would like to know how if you have some $3 \times 3$ matrix with two equal rows, you can prove that the columns are linearly dependent, and that the matrix therefore has no inverse. I am going off the definition of linear independence being that you cannot have a linear combination that equals the zero vector.

PS. I am a total beginner to linear algebra so I may have completely messed up some simple stuff in the question.

Comment: Build a "special" vector with two nonzero entries, and left-multiply your matrix by it. You obtain the zero vector.  Hence, the left null space has dimension greater than zero, which means that the matrix is not full rank.  Thus, matrix multiplication leads to irreversible loss of information. Hence, the lack of invertibility

Answer (score 2):

Let consider [wlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality)

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix} \implies Ax =\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\\ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\\dx_1+ex_2+fx_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}s\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}$$

that is for any vector $x$ the product $Ax$ is a vector with two equal components, therefore column space of $A$ doesn't span $\mathbb R^3$ but at most a subspace with dimension $2$, therefore $A$ is not invertible.

---

As an alternative, given the system

$$Ax =b \iff \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$$

by elimination we obtain the equivalent

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\0&0&0\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2-b_1\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$$

which has not solutions when $b_2-b_1\neq 0 \iff b_1\neq b_2$.

Answer (score 1):

So if a function is not injective it is not invertible. Create the function $f(x)=Ax$ with $A$ and $n \times n$ matrix and $x$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the definition of linear dependence we know that there exists some vectors $x_0 \neq 0$ so that $Ax_0=0$ since one row is a linear combination of the other. However $A0=0$ as well so we have $f(x_0)=f(0)$ and since $x_0 \neq 0$ we know $f(x)$ cannot be injective, and so is not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

The argument can be simply proven. Let us say that the $i$-th row and the $j$-th row of an arbitrary square matrix $X$ are equal for $i\ne j$. Let us say that this matrix, has an inverse $X^{-1}$. According to the definition of matrix multiplication, the entry of the $p$-th row and $q$-th column of $XX^{-1}$ is equal to the inner product of the $p$-th row of $X$ and the $q$-th column of $X^{-1}$. Now consider the $i$-th row of $X$ and the $i$-th column of $X^{-1}$. Since $XX^{-1}=I$, the inner product of the $i$-th row of $X$ and the $i$-th column of $X^{-1}$ should be unity. But this leads to contradiction, since the entry of the $j$-th column and the $i$-th row of $XX^{-1}$ would have to be unity, as opposed to zero. This simple argument, proves that **square matrices with two distinct equal rows do not have inverse.**

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the standard basis of $F^3$ (where $F$ is the field over which the matrix is defined). If two different rows $i$ and $j$ of a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ are identical to each other, then $(e_i-e_j)^TA=0$. If $A$ has an inverse, we will arrive at the contradiction that
$$0=\left((e_i-e_j)^TA\right)A^{-1}=(e_i-e_j)^T(AA^{-1})=(e_i-e_j)^TI_3=(e_i-e_j)^T\neq0.$$
More generally, if an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has linearly dependent rows, so that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_ia_i=0$ (here $a_i$ denotes the $i$-th row of $A$) for some coefficients $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ that are not all zero, then $x^TA=0$ where $x^T= (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\ne0 $. Hence $A^{-1}$ cannot exist, otherwise
$$0=(x^TA)A^{-1}=x^T(AA^{-1})=x^TI_n=x^T\neq0.$$